# Project Build Error:-1: error: Unknown module(s) in QT: qt3support

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu, 64-bit, ubuntu-14.04

I'm trying to run a project in QT Creator 3.0.1 on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64-bit machine.  I've installed libraries that I believe allow for 32-bit compatibility as well.

I get an error labeled:

```
Unknown module(s) in QT: qt3support
```

I have done some searching on this already, and have installed additional libraries, but this didn't fix the issue.  I'm wondering if there's either something else I'm missing or if there's a compatibility issue with my version of Ubuntu.

I searched through the list of similar posts that the website showed me as I was writing, and I installed various QT libraries, but have been unable to fix my issue so far.

EDIT: Here's where the error is coming from:

```
QT += core \
gui \
opengl \
qt3support
```

EDIT 2: My version of Qt Creator is running Qt 5.2.1

Comment: Is this `Qt4` or `Qt5`? Remember that `Qt5` has removed this module: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/portingguide.html

Comment: Oh right.  That's an important detail.  When I check the about page, it says Qt 5.2.1

Answer (score 0):

so drescherjm posted a comment that helped me figure it out.  Qt5 removed support of the module qt3support.  So in order to fix it, I installed Qt4 on my machine.

Then, I opened QtCreator and went to configure my project.   I added my kit to the project and chose to use it.  Instructions for how to do both of those things are here:

Configure Project
http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-configuring-projects.html

Adding a kit:
http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-targets.html